# get difference in minutes in xslt 2.0 minutes-from-duration

Tags: date, xslt, xslt-2.0, difference, minute

i have to dates:  `xs:date(current-date())` and something like this `2017-11-01T09:17:00Z`.
I need to get difference in minutes.

My idea is with `minutes-from-duration()` function, but i don't know how convert the dates to right input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply substract two dates or dateTimes in XSLT/XPath 2 or later with e.g. `current-dateTime() - xs:dateTime('2017-11-01T09:17:00Z')` to get a duration, then you can use your function or other operations like e.g. `(current-dateTime() - xs:dateTime('2017-11-01T09:17:00Z')) div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1M')` which would divide the duration by 1min.